# Show that $Y $ is separable.

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|) $ be a banach space and $(A_n)_n $ be a famile of separable subset of $X$.

Let $Y $ be a linear subset of $X $ which is generated by the union of $(A_n)_n$.

Show that $Y $ is separable.

An idea please.

Answer (score 1):

Each $A_n$ has a dense denumerable set, say $\{a_k^n: k\in\Bbb N\}$. 
Take the (numerable) infinite union of all these sequences: $\{y_j:\, j\in\Bbb N\}:=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{x_k^n:\, k\in\Bbb N\}$.

Now you can take all (finite) linear combinations of the $(y_j)_j$ with RATIONAL coefficients (this can be denoted by ${\rm span}_{\Bbb Q}\{y_j:\, j\in\Bbb N\}$).

It is clear that this is a denumerable set and it is easy to show (using that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$) that this set is dense in $Y$.

Comment: You want to write : $$\{y_j:\, j\in\Bbb N\}:=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{a_k^n:\, k\in\Bbb N\}$$ I think?

Comment: AUCH!!!! yeah!!! of course.... IIll edit my answer

Comment: you can detail your answer please because I am a beginner in separablity

Comment: I think, we have to show that : ${\rm span}_{\Bbb Q}\{y_j:\, j\in\Bbb N\} $ is a set dense in $Y$ but not in $\cup_n A_n $

Comment: Why would that show that $ X $ is separable? we want to show that $ Y $ is separable but not $ X $.

Comment: Sorry again. I did not read properly.

Comment: Why that would show that  $ X $ is separable ?

Comment: is the following statement true? $$\overline {A}=B\Rightarrow  \overline {\text {span}_{\mathbb {Q}}A}=\text {span}_{\mathbb {R}}B $$

Comment: My intuition says "yes".

Comment: Is $X$ a Banach space over the field $\mathbb{R}$?  Or is possible to be $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: If it were $\Bbb C$, just change $\Bbb Q$ by $\Bbb Q+i\Bbb Q$ and everything works,

Comment: @Tito.  if $B$ consists of linearly independent elements (which is possible in any infinite dimensional Banach space) then $\text {span}_R(B) $ cannot be closed since if it were it would be a Banach space with a countably infinite Hamel basis which cannot exist. But clearly $\text {span}_Q(A) $ is closed so the two are not equal.